# Rails Migration Form Error With Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, migration, semantics

I have just built a migration for my movies table called year_id
When I create two new years, 2012 and 2013, I then add the dropdown to select the year
and I get this:

[image]

How can i make my dropdown select show the actual year (2012 or 2013) and not #< Year:0x000 etc...

This is my model:

```
class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :year 
    has_many :movies
end
```

This is my form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @movie, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> 
  <% if @movie.errors.any? %> 
    <div id="error_explanation"> 
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@movie.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this movie from being saved:
      </h2> 
      <ul> 
        <% @movie.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %> 
          <li><%= msg %></li> 
        <% end %> 
      </ul>
    </div> 
  <% end %> 
  <div class="field"> <%=h f.input :year, :include_blank => false %> </div><br />
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your Year model? Thank you

Comment: class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :year

  has_many :movies
end

Comment: Share the code for the select as well please, basically you're getting the object rather than the `year` attribute.

Comment: This is the form 
<%= semantic_form_for @ movie, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @ movie.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@ movie.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this movie from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @ movie.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="field">
    <%=h f.input :year, :include_blank => false %>
  </div><br />

Comment: The @ signs arent normally spaced but stackoverflow wont allow it so changed it for this

Comment: Please update the actual question with the full code for your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the full code for the form it is difficult to answer your question exactly. However, what is happening is the actual instance of your `Year` is being passed as the option text. You would probably see a similar output if you called `to_s` from the console

```
Year.first.to_s
# => "#<Year:0x00000101bcea10>"
```

Take a look at the `options_for_select` documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select to see how to properly define a select element's options.

It looks like you might also be able to use the `collection_select` form helper to save yourself the trouble of defining the options array. It would look something like this

```
<%= f.collection_select :year_id, Year.all, :id, :year %>
```

The last option `:year` is the method that is used for the option text, so you'd change that to something meaningful for your model.

Comment: Yep, he is right, you either need to use collection_select, options_for_select, or options_from_collection_for_select in order to get things to display properly.